# How do I sort out my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

```
Warning--entry type for "antimatteruses" isn't style-file defined
--line 21 of file antimatter.bib

Warning--entry type for "antimatterbombs" isn't style-file defined
--line 31 of file antimatter.bib

Warning--to sort, need author or key in antimatteruses

(There were 3 warnings).
```

These warnings keep on coming, but the other big issue I'm getting is that when I run LaTex for the 1st time when trying to add my bibliography, it wipes my

`.bib` file

```
@mastersthesis{antiprotonanduranium, 
   Author = {Hans-Peter Duerr and Edward Teller}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-09 19:56:07 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-09 20:05:25 +0000}, 
   Rating = {5}, 
   Read = {1}, 
   School = {University of California}, 
   Title = {Interaction of antiprotons with nuclear fields}, 
   Year = {1956}
}
@online{antimatterbombs, 
   Author = {Andre Gsponer and Jean-Pierre Hurni}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-09 19:51:42 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-10 14:55:40 +0000}, 
   Rating = {4}, 
   Read = {1}, 
   Title = {Antimatter Weapons}, 
   Url = {cui.unige.ch/isi/sscr/phys/antim-BPP.html}, 
   Bdsk-Url-1 = {cui.unige.ch/isi/sscr/phys/antim-BPP.html}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a MWE (including the problematic lines in the `.bib` file).

Comment: What kind of entries are `antimatteruses` and `antimatterbombs`? `@article` or something else?

Comment: Maybe you should not use `@webpage`, but `@online`. But that depends on your style. A MWE would still help.

Comment: They are url's. In my bibliography, i also have an article, but it doesn't have any errors

Comment: How am I supposed to change it from {@webpage} to {@online}. The dropdown menu doesn't have online. It only has electronic, url and webpage.

Comment: `bibtex` has no drop-down, it has a CLI. What software are you using?

Comment: Please post the two entries that are giving you trouble, and please indicate which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: Im using BibDesk on Mac. also, I have changed it from webpage to online, but it says that that code is not possible.

Comment: Please edit your post rather than creating a load of comments.

Comment: Is there a reason you won't share with us which bibliography style you employ? (I asked for this piece of information 3 hours ago...)

Answer (score 2):

You may ignore the warnings. If the bibliography style of your choice doesn't recognize a given entry type (e.g., `@webpage`), the default `@misc` entry type is used instead.

Make sure you that use a bibliography style that knows what do with a field called `url`. In the code below, I use the `plainnat` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@mastersthesis{antiprotonanduranium, 
   Author = {Hans-Peter Duerr and Edward Teller}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-09 19:56:07 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-09 20:05:25 +0000}, 
   Rating = {5}, 
   Read = {1}, 
   School = {University of California}, 
   Title = {Interaction of antiprotons with nuclear fields}, 
   Year = {1956}
}
@online{antimatterbombs, 
   Author = {Andre Gsponer and Jean-Pierre Hurni}, 
   Date-Added = {2017-02-09 19:51:42 +0000}, 
   Date-Modified = {2017-02-10 14:55:40 +0000}, 
   Rating = {4}, 
   Read = {1}, 
   Title = {Antimatter Weapons}, 
   Url = {cui.unige.ch/isi/sscr/phys/antim-BPP.html}, 
   Bdsk-Url-1 = {cui.unige.ch/isi/sscr/phys/antim-BPP.html}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{antimatterbombs,antiprotonanduranium}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```